# Typical array program in C++

Tags: c++

I want to create a program in C++ that arranges inputted words in alphabetical order. Can any one help.

I tried arranging taking first letter using for loop but so far it gives me absurd result.  I only want a little hint and will do the rest on own

Comment: [`std::sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) a `std::vector<std::string>` and you're done!

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is easy. The standard library **does all the work for you**. The string has an operator< which is compared **lexicographically**. So really, it's a waste of time. std::sort will call operator< on its parameters.

Warning: by default, lexicographically means it will compare the ASCII values. So the exclamation mark goes before numbers, and numbers go before capital letters, and capital letters go before lowercase letters.

```
string myWords[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    cin >> myWords[i];
sort(begin(myWords), end(myWords));
```

If you have a vector, just do `v.begin()` and `v.end()`.